# Add Images to GetOrgChart that are saved in Database Table as 'blob'

Tags: orgchart

I want to add the images that are saved in my Database Tables as 'BLOB'. As far as I Have checked GetOrgChart takes the Image URL to display the image. Is there any way I can add images that are saved in my Database??

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long search  i found this is not possible. as getorgchart uses the image url to show the images.